# In Python is it possible to execute while loops in a random order?

Tags: python, loops, random

I made a password generator that creates a random set of numbers, letters, and symbols, but the results are always printed in that order. Each character type is created through its own while loop and I'm wondering if there is a way to for the while loops to execute at random rather than in a top down order. Thank you!

```
import random

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
alphabet_up = alphabet.upper()
numz = '0123456789'
symz = '~@!#$%&*'
alpha_character_type = [alphabet, alphabet_up]
index_counter_num = 0
index_counter_letter = 0
index_counter_symz = 0
print('Welcome to password generator')
pw_length = int(input('Please enter password length: '))
if pw_length < 6:
    pw_length = int(input('Password must be at least 6 characters long. Please enter a larger number: '))
letters_num = int(input('Enter desired number of letters: '))
numbers_num = int(input('Enter desired number of numbers: '))
if letters_num + numbers_num>= pw_length:
    print('Please leave room for symbols. Reduce the amount of letters and/or numbers')
    letters_num = int(input('Enter new desired number of letters: '))
    numbers_num = int(input('Enter new desired number of numbers: '))
    characters_left = pw_length - letters_num - numbers_num
    print('Thank you. There is now', characters_left, 'spaces left for symbols. Your password will now be generated' )
print('Here is your password: ')
#NUMBERS LOOP
while index_counter_num < numbers_num:
    selected_numz = random.choice(numz)
    index_counter_num += 1
    print(selected_numz, end= '')
#LETTERS LOOP
while index_counter_letter < letters_num:
    style = random.choice(alpha_character_type)
    style_character = random.choice(style)
    selected_letters = style_character
    index_counter_letter += 1
    print(selected_letters, end= '')
# SYMBOLS LOOP
characters_left = pw_length - letters_num - numbers_num
while index_counter_symz < characters_left:
    selected_symz = random.choice(symz)
    index_counter_symz += 1
    print(selected_symz, end = '')
```

Comment: Why not just shuffle at the end? Or even better (more random), just sample from the entire pool?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you've written so far, so we can more easily adapt it into a solution that works for you?

Comment: @schwobaseggl yes I would love to shuffle at the end, but the way the password is being printed I'm not sure how to claim it as a variable outside the loops (I'm new to this)

Answer (score 1):

A great way is that instead of directly printing the selected character you could first store them in a variable and then shuffle it. You could do this by initializing a list variable before the loops start and adding the characters to it. After the loops, shuffle it using random.shuffle() and then join the characters using the .join() function.

Final code:

```
import random

final_password = []
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
alphabet_up = alphabet.upper()
numz = '0123456789'
symz = '~@!#$%&*'
alpha_character_type = [alphabet, alphabet_up]
index_counter_num = 0
index_counter_letter = 0
index_counter_symz = 0
print('Welcome to password generator')
pw_length = int(input('Please enter password length: '))
if pw_length < 6:
    pw_length = int(input('Password must be at least 6 characters long. Please enter a larger number: '))
letters_num = int(input('Enter desired number of letters: '))
numbers_num = int(input('Enter desired number of numbers: '))
if letters_num + numbers_num>= pw_length:
    print('Please leave room for symbols. Reduce the amount of letters and/or numbers')
    letters_num = int(input('Enter new desired number of letters: '))
    numbers_num = int(input('Enter new desired number of numbers: '))
    characters_left = pw_length - letters_num - numbers_num
    print('Thank you. There is now', characters_left, 'spaces left for symbols. Your password will now be generated' )
print('Here is your password: ')
#NUMBERS LOOP
while index_counter_num < numbers_num:
    selected_numz = random.choice(numz)
    index_counter_num += 1
    final_password.append(selected_numz)
#LETTERS LOOP
while index_counter_letter < letters_num:
    style = random.choice(alpha_character_type)
    style_character = random.choice(style)
    selected_letters = style_character
    index_counter_letter += 1
    final_password.append(selected_letters)
# SYMBOLS LOOP
characters_left = pw_length - letters_num - numbers_num
while index_counter_symz < characters_left:
    selected_symz = random.choice(symz)
    index_counter_symz += 1
    final_password.append(selected_symz)
    
random.shuffle(final_password)
print("".join(final_password))
```

I have checked the code and it gives the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

### Shuffle

1. Create a list of the items you want to iterate through.
2. Shuffle that list using (for example) `random.shuffle()` function.
3. Iterate through that list.

This will result in random order without repetition. If you want to pick random elements potentially with repetition, then you need to randomly sample from that pool.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute code blocks in a random order if you put them in functions. The functions can be put in a list and executed in a random order with the help of `random.choices` (if you don't want the same loop repeated twice, use `random.shuffle` instead)

```
import random

def func1():
    print("This is func1")
    while False: # your first while loop here
        pass

def func2():
    print("This is func2")
    while False: # your second while loop here
        pass

funcs = [func1, func2]

random.seed()

for f in random.choices(funcs, k=len(funcs)):
    f()
```